# How to pass an onChange function from a parent to child component in material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I'm new to react and material UI and I'm trying to make a dropdown select component. I want to be able to pass onChange functions to the component from the parent, and I've followed the official documentation, but selecting the option doesn't seem to do anything.

This is the child component:

```
export default function AutocompleteForm(props) {
  const {label, array, handleSubmit} = props
  
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={array}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label}
      onChange={handleSubmit} />}
    />
  )
}
```

I pass it a label, an array of options to display and an onChange function.

In the parent, I have this:

```
const Form = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const handleSelect = (event, newvalue) => {
        console.log(newvalue)
        setLabel(newvalue)
      }
    const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
    
    return (
    <AutocompleteForm array={options} label="Pick an option" handleSubmit={handleSelect}/>)

}
```

However, I don't see the value from my handleSelect function displayed to the console, and the value is not updated either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: You should not use reserved words for props. Try renaming props to something other than function.

Comment: oh sorry, its not actually named function in my code. I renamed it here to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed some errors you have.

First don't name a prop `function` since it is a reserved word, like the one you are using to create the components

Second your are closing the `renderInput` and `Textfield` in the `onChange`

And third the `setLabel` I don't know where it comes from it must be the `setValue` you have from the useState or you can rename the setValue for setLabel

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

function AutocompleteForm({ array, handleSelect, label }) {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={array}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} />}
      onChange={handleSelect}
    />
  );
}

const Form = () => {
  const [, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const handleSelect = (event, newvalue) => {
    console.log(newvalue);
    setValue(newvalue);
  };
  const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"];

  return (
    <AutocompleteForm
      array={options}
      label="Pick an option"
      handleSelect={handleSelect}
    />
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Comment: Thank you Marx! Closing the `Textfield` in `onChange` was the problem!

Comment: If you install a linter this won't happen anymore, it is a must!

Answer (score 0):

This solution passes the onChange function to the Autocomplete component in the AutocompleteForm and provides parameters to it. The onChange function uses an event (event) and the new value (newValue) for its parameters in order to update the value in the parent component and log it to the console. This should make the dropdown select component fully functional.

Change name of function to "handleSelect"

```
export default function AutocompleteForm(props) {
  const {label, array, handleSelect} = props
  
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={array}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => handleSelect(event, newValue)} />}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Look that the code is wrong, you still close the renderInput and Texfield in the onChange